# how can i creating dynamic size array of objects by new without using default constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic, default-constructor

As the title says, is there a way to create a dynamic size array of objects with new, with this condition that I don't want to call the default constructor ?

something like :

```
myclass* myarray = new myclass(firstArgument, secondArgument)[32];
```

Comment: Just use an `std::vector<myclass>`. `std::Vector<myclass>(32, myclass(firstArg, secondArg));`.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is by not using `new` but to use `std::vector` which has a constructor that can copy-construct the vector elements. That would be the recommended way in most cases. Needing a dynamically allocated array instead of a vector is a pretty rare case.

If you *have* to use new (for whatever reason), then one way to do this is to allocate raw memory, cast it to your object type and then use [`std::uninitialized_fill()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/uninitialized_fill/) to copy construct your values in-place.

Comment: Slight quibble: if you're implementing `std::vector` then you'd use the vector's allocator, not `new`. +1 anyway.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Noted, edited, harshly reflected on own denseness. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you need a dynamic array you can use vector, that will also take off your hands the memory management.

[vector c++ reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no way (or at least easy way) to do this (with new).

after a lots of searching I came up with this solution:

```
 USE VECTOR CLASS
```

actually forget about new and for your typical projects, use vector. it has lots of benefits.